# brew/mongodb doesn't stop when I close terminal

Tags: macos, homebrew, mongodb

I installed mongodb with brew and I didn't load the launchctl plist.

When I run the mongod command to start the server in foreground and suddenly close my iTerm the mongodb process stays up and I don't want that.

Why is this? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Exit the process before you close the terminal.  You can do this by pressing `Ctrl-C`.  It's somewhat odd that iTerm is not killing processes when you close tabs/windows - it's supposed to, but some Googling suggest you are not the only one to see this issue (I didn't see an obvious solution for it).

If you forget to `Ctrl-C` and the `mongod` is still hanging around after the close, just find the process and kill it:

```
ps aux | grep mongod
# get the pid of the process from the above command
kill <PID>
```

Or, for a one liner:

```
kill $(pidof mongod)
```

MongoDB will exit normally when you do use a regular kill, so no worries on that front.

Comment: I see but the problem is not related to iTerm and ZSH, I used terminal.app and bash and same thing happens. I don't understand how the process keeps running with my session being closes, I think it's somehow something related to mongodb itself..

Comment: "the problem" is not a problem.  It is by design.  How is anyone supposed to use this if it is dependent on your terminal session?  Please research services or daemons.. it might make sense then.

Answer (score 0):

It is running as a service in the background.

You can search for services and open the app.
Then search for MongoDB Server and in its properties, change its startup type from automatic to manual.

Then from now, you are supposed to type `mongod` in a terminal to start MongoDB server.